# Commit ammended on different branch

Tags: git

I have following structure of commits/branches:

```
|
*   03dd257 - (HEAD, solutions) ...
|\  
| * 7976266 - (master) ...
* | 9ce9158 - ...
|/  
* d2a4d81 - ...
```

My flow is:

- commit d2a4d81 (master)
- create branch solutions
- commit 9ce9158 (solutions)
- commit 7976266 (master)
- merge master to solutions (commit 03dd257)
- **ammend commit 7976266 on master**

Now my commit is different on master and solutions. How can I safely update commit 7976266 on branch solutions?

These are all local changes so there is should be no problem with pushing once I solve this locally.

I have further changes on solutions branch so I can't simply reset to 9ce9158 and merge again.

Comment: I think a simple merge will be ok if you are not care about the commit content.

Answer (score 0):

If you do, merge commit will still point to old (not amended) commit, and your tree will look like this:

```
|   *  XXXXXXX - amended commit
*   |  03dd257 - (HEAD, solutions) ...
|\  |
| * | 7976266 - (old master) ...
* |/ 9ce9158 - ...
|/  
* d2a4d81 - ...
```

What you might want to do is reset solutions branch back to before merge and do a new merge. If you haven't published anything yet (and since you amend stuff, you probably didn't), it's OK to do so.

Comment: It's not really what I want, since I have some other commits after 03dd257 and don't want to loose them. Actually I did reset because it was only one small commit but for future it would be nice to have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the new commit generated by amending `7976266` is `7976266-v2`.

I presume you want changes in `7976266-v2` appears in `solutions` too, without complicating the graph too much.

First, create a `amend` branch at `7976266-v2`:

```
git branch amend 7976266-v2
```

Then 'rebase' changes between `7976266` and `7976266-v2` onto `solution`

```
git rebase --onto solutions 7976266 amend
```

This should create a new commit after `03dd257`, which contains changes between `7976266` and `7976266-v2`, and is pointed to by `amend` branch now.

```
  * sth_new - (amend)
|/
*   03dd257 - (solutions) ...
|\  
| * 7976266 - (master) ...
* | 9ce9158 - ...
|/  
* d2a4d81 - ...
```

Now you can merge `amend` onto `solutions` when you want.

Comment: finally i didn't use it, i reseted to 9ce9158 and merged one more time. However, as far as I can see your answer partially solves the problem, so I can accept it if only you update the 'diagram' of branches, which would look like in aragaer's answer (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I believe this is what we can get using `rebase`. To my understanding, what it does is to find the latest common ancestor of 2 commits (d2a4d81), copy span of path (7976266 -- d2a4d81 -- amend ) onto `solutions` by replaying changes, and point `amend` to tip of sth_new.